# How to insert bits into a BIT field from an expression or string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 52 `boolean` fields. They are specific flags for each record.

To make indexing faster/easier, as well as being able to make the combination of those flags `unique`, I inserted a new column called *flags* as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN flags BIT(52);
```

Now, I can insert values into that column manually, using this notation:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (flags) values (b'0011000101');
```

**However**, I want to be able to just update the field *flags* across all records from the data already present on the boolean fields I already have populated. Something like:

```
UPDATE myTable SET flags = CONCAT(myBoolean1, myBoolean2, myBoolean3, ... myBoolean52);
```

**That, of course, doesn't work** as the `CONCAT`function produces a *varchar(52)* of ones and zeros.

I've been trying with different parameters on `CAST` and `CONV` without success. And I don't see an obvious way to make something like `b'00101011'` work from an expression instead of the quoted ones and zeros.

How can I populate a `BIT` type field from an expresion that builds the bits from other booland fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use try CONV function (I have not tried it with BIT type):

```
UPDATE
    myTable
SET
    flags = 0 + CONV(CONCAT(myBoolean1, myBoolean2, myBoolean3, ... myBoolean52), 2, 10)
;
```

OR

```
UPDATE
    myTable
SET
    flags = CAST(CONV(CONCAT(myBoolean1, myBoolean2, myBoolean3, ... myBoolean52), 2, 10) AS UNSIGNED)
;
```

Explanation:

`CONCAT` -- convert your 1/0 values into binary string ('1', '1', '0' => '110')

`CONV` -- convert binary string into dec string ('110' => '6')

`CAST` or `0 +` - convert dec string into int ('6' => 6)

My concern, however is this:

> To make indexing faster/easier

People usually using bitmasks to filter by exact bits. 
Unfortunately, MySQL will not use indexes in this case.